# Vue.js permanently add filter to component

Tags: vue.js

I'm wanted to force the running of a filter on a component everytime it's used. I know I can add a filter to a component in it's markup, but in this instance the filter is to be considered "required", or "core" functionality of the component.

For example, the below component and filter can be used like: `<my-component v-model="amount | custom-currency" name="my-field"></my-component>`

What I'm ultimately wanting to achieve is the same behavior, but with the markup only looking like: `<my-component v-model="amount" name="my-field"></my-component>`

The examples are based on the currency filter example outlined here: http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-filter.html#Two-way_Filters

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated

Component and filter for reference:

```
var CurrencyComponent = Vue.extend({
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    filter: 'customCurrency',
    template: '<input type="text" name="{{ name }}" >'
});

Vue.filter('customCurrency', {
    read: function(val, symbol) {
        if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
            return symbol + val.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
        return symbol + '0';
    },
    write: function(val, oldVal) {
        var number = +val.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        return isNaN(number) ? 0 : parseFloat(number.toFixed(2))
    }
});
```

EDIT:

In reference to Dewey's answer:

```
var CurrencyComponent = Vue.extend({
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        'hehe2': function() {
            return this.$eval('hehe | custom-currency');
        }
    },
    template: '<input type="text" name="{{ name }}" >'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use computed properties.
Make 2 variables: one variable as input, and the other as the filtered input. Something like:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="asInput" />
  <h1>{{ asOutput }}</h1>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({

  el: '#app',
  data: {
    asInput: ''
  },
  computed: {
    'asOutput': function() {
      return this.$eval('asInput | yourCustomFilter');
    }
  }
});
```

See the working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/7ae9t9wv/
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible for me to put a computed or equivalent property on the component definition directly? I've added an example to the original question for reference

Comment: I'm not really sure about your custom-filter, but I've updated my jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/7ae9t9wv/1/ perhaps thats what youre looking for?